# Clicking an image does not display the textContent

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a Rock, Paper, and Scissors game. Most of the time, when I click the rock image, the text content (`computerPicked.textContent`) will be displayed below the image; however, sometimes when I refresh the page and click the rock image, the text content would not appear. There were times when I had to click the rock image 3-5 times until the text content appeared below it.

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let values = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'],
    valueToUse = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
  return valueToUse;
};

const rock = document.getElementById('rock');
let playerPicked = document.getElementsByClassName('playerPicked')[0];
let computerPicked = document.getElementsByClassName('computerPicked')[0];
let result = document.getElementsByClassName('result')[0];

rock.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (computerPlay() === 'Rock') {
    computerPicked.textContent = "Computer Pick: Rock";
  } else if (computerPlay() === 'Paper') {
    computerPicked.textContent = "Computer Pick: Paper";
  } else if (computerPlay() === 'Scissors') {
    computerPicked.textContent = "Computer Pick: Scissors";
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
  <h2 id="choose">Choose:</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button>
    <img id="rock" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477914-200.png">
  </button>
  <button>
    <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477922-200.png">
  </button>
  <button>
    <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477919-200.png">
  </button>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class='playerPicked'></p>
  <p class='computerPicked'></p>
  <p class='result'></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are calling `computerPlay()` at every condition, therefore it plays more than once every time a condition fails. Just call it once like `let comp = computerPlay()` and use `comp` in your conditions.

Comment: FYI, `document.querySelector('.playerPicked')` is a lot shorter than `document.getElementsByClassName('playerPicked')[0]`

Comment: @StackSlave Thank you! sorry, I am beginner in Javascript. Out of curiosity, why would a assigning a function to a variable fix this? does this mean that a variable  does not play more than once?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you should call `computerPlay()` only once per click and then save the returned value to a variable. If you don't, `computerPlay()` will return a completely new, random value each time it is called (the value will keep changing making it really hard to compare against). e.g.

`const compMove = computerPlay();`

Note that here we are assigning the *returned value of calling the function* to the variable `compMove`, and not a reference to the function itself.

---

The other helpful point of feedback in the comments is that you can use `document.querySelector(.myClass)` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')[0]` to help shorten your code.

---

Also, instead of attaching click handlers one by one, you can use `document.querySelectorAll` to attach a handler to all the buttons at once with `forEach`. While iterating through the collection of buttons, you can extract data about the move from a data attribute. eg

- `<button data-move="rock">`
- `const playerMove = e.currentTarget.dataset.move`

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let values = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'],
    valueToUse = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
  return valueToUse;
};

const moves = document.querySelectorAll('button');
let playerPicked = document.querySelector('.playerPicked');
let computerPicked = document.querySelector('.computerPicked');
let result = document.querySelector('.result');

moves.forEach(move => move.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const compMove = computerPlay();
  const playerMove = e.currentTarget.dataset.move
  computerPicked.textContent = `Computer Picked: ${compMove}`;
  playerPicked.textContent = `You Picked: ${playerMove}`;
}));
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
  <h2 id="choose">Choose:</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button data-move="Rock">
    <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477914-200.png">
  </button>
  <button data-move="Paper">
    <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477922-200.png">
  </button>
  <button data-move="Scissors">
    <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477919-200.png">
  </button>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class='playerPicked'></p>
  <p class='computerPicked'></p>
  <p class='result'></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great but I think editing the textContent for `playerPicked.textContent` from `'Computer Pick: ${playerMove}'` to `'Player Pick: ${playerMove}'` or `'You Picked: ${playerMove}'` this demo would be perfect. Still **+1** for this solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea was this ...

You put to draw and display the draw and not the choice of the person.

I fixed the possibility of the computer choosing the same as the player.

html

```js
                function listen(obj) {
                    obj.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        let computerPicked = document.querySelector("h3");
                        let playerPicked = document.querySelector(".player");
                        playerPicked.textContent = `Player Pick: ${obj.id}`;
                        computerPicked.textContent = `Computer Pick: ${computerPlay(obj.id)}`;
                    });
                }

                function computerPlay(except) {
                    let values;
                    switch (except) {
                        case 'Rock':
                            values = ['Paper', 'Scissors'];
                            break;
                        case 'Paper':
                            values = ['Rock', 'Scissors']
                            break;
                        case 'Scissors':
                            values = ['Rock', 'Paper']
                            break;
                    }
                    valueToUse = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
                    return valueToUse;
                };

                const rock = document.querySelector('#rock');
                const Paper = document.querySelector('#Paper');
                const Scissors = document.querySelector('#Scissors');

                let playerPicked = document.getElementsByClassName('playerPicked')[0];
                let computerPicked = document.getElementsByClassName('computerPicked')[0];
                let result = document.getElementsByClassName('result')[0];

                listen(Rock);
                listen(Paper);
                listen(Scissors);
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
                  <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</h1>
                  <h2 id="choose">Choose:</h2>
                  <h3 class="computer"> 
                  </h3>
                    <h3 class="player"> 
                  </h3>
                  <h3 class="whoWins"> 
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                  <button>
                    <img id="Rock" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477914-200.png">
                  </button>
                  <button>
                    <img id="Paper" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477922-200.png">
                  </button>
                  <button>
                    <img id='Scissors' src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/477919-200.png">
                  </button>
                </div>
```